# Extracting definition of customized messages from bag files

Tags: ros, rosbag, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

TL;DR: How can write a node that subscribes to topics under customized messages that's published from a bag when I don't have access to the definition of the customized messages (the .msg files)?

I have a bag file containing topics in customized messages, for example `dbw_mkz_msgs/SteeringReport`.
While I don't have access to the `dbw_mkz_msgs` or the definition of `dbw_mkz_msgs/SteeringReport`, I can use tools such as `rqt_bag` or `rostopic echo -b` to view them (their fields and values to be more specific). I can even use the `rosbag` python api to edit them and write to another bag.

However, what I cannot do is write a node that subscribes to one of these topics in `dbw_mkz_msgs/SteeringReport` since I cannot `from dbw_mkz_msgs.msgs import SteeringReport`. Is there a way to extract the definition of a customized message from a bag file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230120/extracting-definition-of-customized-messages-from-bag-files/) by [shihyuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/26392/shihyuan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2016-03-24

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-03-25**:
In python, have a look at the `get_type_and_topic_info()` function on the bag, http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Cookbook#Get_lists_of_topics_and_types_from_a_bag and http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/rosbag/html/python/

**Comment by [shihyuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/26392/shihyuan/) on 2016-03-25**:
Thanks for you response, @ahendrix. However, it seems like get_type_and_topic_info() will give me the type of the message (a string `dbw_mkz_msg/SteeringReport`), and its md5hash. It still doesn't give me the `SteeringReport()` class that I would get if I had access to the `dbw_mkz_msgs` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So, the full message definitions are captured in the bag file, but there doesn't appear to be a direct API for extracting them.

This kind of does the trick:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rosbag
import sys

types = {}

for bagname in sys.argv[1:]:
    bag = rosbag.Bag(bagname)
    for topic, msg, t in bag.read_messages():
        if not msg._type in types:
            types[msg._type] = msg._full_text


for t in types:
    print "Message type:", t
    print "Message text:"
    print types[t]
    print
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shihyuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/26392/shihyuan/) on 2016-03-30**:
Awesome! With the definition I can recreate a mock `dbw_mkz_msgs` pkg! Thanks a lot.

**Comment by [vschmidt](https://answers.ros.org/users/25950/vschmidt/) on 2021-09-21**:
This should totally be in the ros_bag utility. Awesome!